# fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h no such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute tutorial01.c using gcc and I have the gcc and tutorial01.c in the same folder along with libavcodec and libavformat and its associated files it gives me this error

> fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h no such file or directory compilation terminated

when I run  `gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lz` through the terminal in ubuntu 12.04

the code is

```
#include  libavcodec/avcodec.h
#include libavformat/avformat.h
#include stdio.h

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame)
 {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);
  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
  int             i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx;
  AVCodec         *pCodec;
  AVFrame         *pFrame; 
  AVFrame         *pFrameRGB;
  AVPacket        packet;
  int             frameFinished;
  int             numBytes;
  uint8_t         *buffer;

  if(argc < 2) 
  {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();
  // Open video file
  if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);
  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }

  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();

  if(pFrameRGB==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer              
 numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);

  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
 {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) 
    {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, 
               packet.data, packet.size);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) 
      {
        // Convert the image from its native format to RGB




    img_convert((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, 
                    (AVPicture*)pFrame, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, 
                    pCodecCtx->height);




    // Save the frame to disk

    if(++i<=5)
  SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
   }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_free(pFrameRGB);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);

 // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);


  // Close the video file
  av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting (four leading spaces) for your code, please!

Comment: Did you compile and build libavcodec and libavformat? Or are you using a prebuilt development package for your platform?

Comment: i used prebuild development package

Comment: How did you solve it, if you did?

Answer (score 4):

That error occur due to error in path

-L/home/yourpath/ffmpeg_build/lib/

-I/home/yourpath/ffmpeg_build/include/

ffmpeg_build – Where the files will be built and libraries installed.

Example :

create file "execute.sh "

NOW open file and paste the following code :

```
g++ -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-write-strings -L/home/yourpath/ffmpeg_build/lib/ -I/home/yourpath/ffmpeg_build/include/ -o output program.cpp -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lavdevice -lswresample -lswscale -lm -lva -lpthread -lvorbis -lvpx -lopus -lz -lpostproc -ldl -lfdk-aac -lmp3lame -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile -lx264 -ltheora -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -ldl -lrt -lx265 -lbz2
```

and type:  sh execute.sh and binary will be created in the name "output"
then type ./output for output.

Note : above for C++ , for c code change g++ to gcc

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the path to the libavcodec and libavformat include files to your command line. Find the include/ directory and add

```
-Ipath/to/include
```

for each of the relevant include files.

You'll also need to do the same thing for the library directories, using -L.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Suppose my path to mk file is: D:\ffmpeg\jni.. I then run an NDK-build to compile it but I get this error for no such file. How to add this path?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you install your ffmpeg.
Generally, you can compile and install with 3 steps:

1. ./configure --prefix=/yourpath/ffmpeg
2. make
3. make install

If you configured without "--prefix" parameter, it is installed at your default path.(on my Ubuntu, I found ffmpeg has been installed at "/usr/local/")

After install ffmpeg correctly, you may use following command to compile your code:

```
gcc testFfmpeg.c -I/yourpath/ffmpeg/include/ -L/yourpath/ffmpeg/lib/
```

or

```
gcc testFfmpeg.c -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/
```