# Why can't we find the header file that actually exists?

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

I am a C language beginners, I encountered a problem, can not find the header file, but in fact, these header files are in the current file, I saw online methods (for example : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127397/fatal-error-libavcodec-avcodec-h-no-such-file-or-directory-compilation-terminat)) are to add - I option can solve this problem, but I am very curious, why can't it find itself, can only rely on - I option?

include path:

```
ls .
include  test_ffmpeg.c
ls include/libavcodec/
avcodec.h  avfft.h    dirac.h       dxva2.h  vaapi.h  vdpau.h    videotoolbox.h   xvmc.h
avdct.h    d3d11va.h  dv_profile.h  qsv.h    vda.h    version.h  vorbis_parser.h
```

source tree:

```
root
 |-----test_ffmpeg.c 
 |-----include
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "./include/libavcode/avcodec.h"
#include "./include/libvformat/acfomat.h"
#include "./include/libavfilter/avfilter.h"

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
gcc test_ffmpeg.c  -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavutil
```

a fatal error occured:

```
test_ffmpeg.c:3:10: fatal error: ./include/libavcode/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
#include "./include/libavcode/avcodec.h"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Include is relative of the source file that is including.

Comment: Added a little information, my source file and header file are the same directory.

Answer (score 6):

Your include statement mentions `include/libavcode`, but the path that exists is `include/libavcodec`.

Add a `c` and you should see a difference.